# Make the timer work even when the site does not running or cause the site to be active all the time

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I need to activate a function at 11 pm.

I made a timer that runs and checks whether the time is 11 sent to the function.
But the timer runs only while the site is running so that the nighttime timer stops working.

Is it possible to make the site run all the time and not only when people are active on the site or cause the timer to run even while the site is not running?

The timer works great during the day - while the site runs.

I'd be happy if you could attach an example of an answer code.
Here is my code that works only when the site is running.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Timers.Timer timScheduledTask = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timScheduledTask.Interval =(60 * 1000);
    timScheduledTask.Enabled = true;
    timScheduledTask.Elapsed +=
    new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timScheduledTask_Elapsed);
    timScheduledTask.Start();
}

private void timScheduledTask_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((DateTime.Now.Hour==23 && DateTime.Now.Minute==0))
    {
        Functions.sendEmailEquipment();
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'm using the Windows Task Scheduler for this. Create a Solution with (at least) three projects: Common runtime/business logic, ASP.NET website (using the runtime), console application (also using the runtime). then configure the Windows Task Scheduler to run the console application at appropriate intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You should create Task Scheduler for this purpose this more reliable and efficient approach to use because it is managed by OS. it guarantees the execution.
SO you should follow this basic steps

1. Create Console App which contains your code. Get .exe file of that console app on the server
2. Create Task Scheduler to execute every day at 11.00 and give a path of exe in Action.

Here is

[How to create basic tasks with Task Scheduler, in 5 steps](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard)